# Share Direct Message (DM) from Flutter App to Messenger and Instagram

Tags: flutter, share

I want to share a text as direct message (DM), from my flutter app to Messenger and Instagram direct.
The user will click on icon within the app to open the right social media. I don't wan't to open the system window with all apps available.
It's already working for What's app or Twitter. I click on an icon and it's open a link which open message with filled text.
I use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package to do it
example : 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=$text&url=$url'

Comment: Which package you use to share the text ? share_plus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to use deep link and open it with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) lib  :

- Instagram : https://www.instagram.com/direct/new/
- Messenger : http://m.me/

I do a copy to clipboard just before and inform user.

Comment: is there any way to pass it a predefine message and open the ''sent-to-many'' window?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the package `share_plus` (https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus).

Comment: it displays the window share system, not expected behavior.

Comment: You are thinking of explicit intents and not implicit intents for Android. I have not used or even study this but there is a package `intent` that may do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

The most popular plugin is `share`: [link here](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

Comment: it displays the window share system, not expected behavior.